# Cannot pass sregex_iterator as a stream to cout

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, iterator

I save the following file as first.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    regex filenameRegex("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+");

    string s2 = "Filenames are readme.txt and my.cmd.";

    sregex_iterator it(s2.begin(), s2.end(), filenameRegex);
    sregex_iterator it_end;

    while(it != it_end){
        cout << (*it) << endl;
        ++it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile it with the command g++ first.cpp -o first -std=c++11 produces the following error:

```
first.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
first.cpp:16:15: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
   cout << (*it) << endl;
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from first.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> > >]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

I am very confused about what is going on here. The tutorial [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2079020) states that deferenceing an sregex_iterator object should return a string. Is this not true?

Comment: The tutorial is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::sregex_iterator` is an iterator over `std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`. To get a `std::string` out of it, you'd need to use the `str()` method:

```
while(it != it_end){
    std::cout << it->str() << '\n';
    ++it;
}
```

BTW, don't use [`std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/).

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to provide any more info on the error message? It looks like it's saying that *it returns the type std::basic_ostream<char>&&

Comment: @HarryBraviner: the error message just states that there is no output operator for `std::match_results<...>`. The reason it states that in a somewhat odd way is that there is a templated overload which takes an arbitrary second parameter and an `std::basic_ostream<...>&&` as first argument.